# magento export get real image url instead of cached image url

Tags: catalog, export

I want to get the products real image url instead of the cached one for my export script. Below is my code

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
define('MAGENTO_ROOT', getcwd());
$compilerConfig = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/includes/config.php';
if (file_exists($compilerConfig)) {
    include $compilerConfig;
}
$mageFilename = MAGENTO_ROOT . '/app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
Mage::app(); 
$storeId = 15; //id store
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeId));
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);//attivo prodotto 1 o 0
$lines = array();
//parte stampo prima riga
$lines[] = array("Prodotto SKU","Nome Prodotto","Prezzo Prodotto","Prodotto URL","Descrizione Prodotto","Immagine URL","Categoria Prodotto");
//arreizzo tutti i dati sotto
foreach ($collection as $product) {
    $line = array();
    $line[] = $product->getName();//Nome Prodotto
    $line[] = 'dddd-->'.$product->getThumbnail();
    // Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image')->__toString(); //Immagine URL IN CACHE

    $categories = $product->getCategoryCollection();  
    $categoryNames = array();
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        $categoryNames[] = $category->getName();
    } 
    $line[] = implode(' | ', $categoryNames); //Categoria Prodotto INFAME
    $lines[] = $line;
}


foreach ($lines as $line) {
    echo '"'.implode('","', $line).'"'."\n";
}
```

Comment: You're getting the thumbnail with `$product->getThumbnail()`, why not do the same with `$product->getImage()`?

Comment: hey $product->getThumbnail() and $product->getImage() is not working

Comment: What is missing from those? Can you be more specific?

Comment: i want to get image url but i am unble to get it , when i use Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image')->__toString() it give cache url

Comment: Ok but what does `getImage` return? Normally it's the path of the file from `media/catalog/product`

Answer (score 1):

**There few debug process to check why getThumbnail() & getImage() does give proper result.**

- `getThumbnail() & getImage()` are two getter of product media images
  which give image url after `YourMagento/media/catalog/product` folder.
  It does not give full url Like `YourInstnaceurl//media/catalog/product/A/b/abc.jpd`

If you want then you need to your media url and append the url with  `getThumbnail() & getImage()` .

Then you can below code getting thumbnail & Image url respectively

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($product->getThumbnail());
```

**Or**

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($product->getImage());
```

- **Mage::getSingleton('catalog_product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($product->getImage())**
  does not give the value  proper value whenever `product->getImage()`.

Same thing for `$product->getThumbnail()`

Also.as you using product collection model then you need to filter the collection  by  store id `$collection->addStoreFilter('YOUR_Current_Store_Id')`

- Need to check image, thumbail field exit on `catalog_product_flat_15`
  Table if Flat Setting is enable.
  If not then you need enable those for flat setting